# Why is QMutex used in this code?

Tags: qt, mutex, qthread, qmutex

I was reading someone else's code and I encountered this piece of code that is part of a multi - threaded application .This code is part of the `run()` function in a class which is inherited from **QThread**.
I thought **QMutex** is used for protecting a variable from being changed by several threads simultaneously . But here `stopped` is a member of the class. So it will be created for each instance of the class.
 Am I wrong about mutexes? Has the programmer written a wrong code :) ? Or here mutex has another application?

```
void aThread::run(){
   aMutex.lock();
   if (stopped)
   {
     stopped=false;
     aMutex.unlock();
     break;
   }
   aMutex.unlock();
}
```

Here is the declaration of the stopped :

```
class aThread : public QThread{
public :
   void run();
private:
    volatile bool stopped;
}
```

Comment: Either multiple threads can get to the same object instance _or_ `stopped` is static and shared between instances. You may want to show the declaration of `stopped`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson ~> updated :)

Comment: Is that really the implementation of `run`?  If so, they've written a thread that sets a single boolean, then quits.  If someone really wants that, it would be surprising.

Comment: @TomW ~> No this is not the whole of the run function.

Comment: @saeed: Okay, then, that makes a lot more sense!  I'd assume, then, that some other thread has access to that `stopped` member variable (it's declared `volatile` so that's probably the intention).  If so, then that other thread should hopefully be using that same `aMutex`.  There's nothing necessarily wrong with that.... my guess would be that a condition variable like `QWaitCondition` would be a better solution, but without seeing the rest of the code, that's just a guess.

Comment: Where stopped is set to true? Is there a public setter function for that? If there is, it should also use the mutex. If the stopped is set to true only inside the thread, then the mutex seems to be quite unnecessary.

Comment: @Roku ~> No it doesn't have any setter function!